# Why am I getting a "PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object" while using transactions and prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions, prepared-statement

Like the title says, I am attempting to use both PHP/MySQLi transactions and prepared statements, but I keep getting the "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object" error, and I cannot figure out why.

```
<?php
    $dbConnection = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);

    $query01 = "delete from model where make_id = ?";
    $query02 = "delete from make where id = ?";

    if($stmt01 = $dbConnection->prepare($query01) && $stmt02 = $dbConnection->prepare($query02)){
        if($stmt01->bind_param('i',$id) && $stmt02->bind_param('i',$id)){
            if($stmt01->execute()){
                if($stmt02->execute()){
                    $dbConnection->commit();
                    $dbConnection->commit();
                }
                else{
                    $dbConnection->rollback();
                    $dbConnection->rollback();
                }
            }
            else{
                $dbConnection->rollback();
            }
        }
        else{
            // do something ...
        }
    }
    else{
        // do something ...
    }
?>
```

What I was doing when I got the error, was testing the rollback should an error occur. I replaced the `prepare` "if" statement with "false", and everything worked great. I replaced the `bind` "if" statement with "false", and everything worked out great. However, when I replaced the `$stmt01->execute()` "if" statement with a "false", this is where I got the error. The weird thing is that I got the error on the bind "if" statement line (the line above where I just tested with "false") and not the line itself.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your error message suggests that at least one of your `prepare()` calls has failed. You're not checking that you've opened the connection successfully. Is it possible that it's failed even before you prepare your queries?

Comment: Side note: It looks like you really should be using a foreign-key constraint on `model`, referring to `make`. If you do you can use `ON DELETE CASCADE` and deleting the `make` row will automatically delete all the related `model` rows.

Comment: I am 99% sure that it has not failed before the prepare. Even if it did, or even if any of the prepare statements did fail, the if/else should catch anything like that. Also, I am using a foreign key constraint on model, referring to make - `foreign key (make_id) references MAKE(ID)`, but I did not know of this `ON DELETE CASCADE` of which you speak.

Comment: @Brian and where was $id defined, I dont see that part bro

Comment: $id is passed in. I didn't include it into my snippet up above.